# Migrating from sencha 1 to sencha 2, in eclipse with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am currently working through the tutorials in the book Beginning PhoneGap. I have just completed the sencha touch tutorial. Im trying to migrate the sencha from this tutorial from sencha 1 to 2 following the http://www.sencha.com/learn/upgrading-to-sencha-touch-2-pr2 but im getting a lot of nothing. Below is the first panel i tried to migrate but all i get is a white screen, any help would be appreciated.

```
Ext.setup({
tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
icon: 'icon.png',
glossOnIcon: false,

onReady: function(){ 
    var lastPanelId = 0;
    var SEARCHPAGE=0;
    var TABPAGE=1;
    var FAVPAGE=2;
    var DETAILSPAGE=3;
    var cachedDetails=null;

        Ext.define(' var searchPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.form.FormPanel',

         config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        fullscreen: true,
        scroll: 'vertical',
        standardSubmit: false,
         },

          items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Local Search',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'search',
                label: 'Search',
                value: 'Pizza',
                useClearIcon: true,
                autoCapitalize: false
            }, {
                xtype: 'sliderfield',
                name: 'range',
                label: 'Range (0-10 Kms)',
                value: 5,
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 10
            }]
        }]            //Docking a toolbar at bottom         
        ,
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'spacer'
            }, {
                text: 'Search',
                iconCls: 'search',
                title: 'Search',
                iconMask: true,
                ui: 'round',
                ui: 'confirm',


                handler: function(){
                    lastPanelId=TABPAGE;
                    fetchFromGoogle();
                    mainPanel.dockedItems.items[0].setTitle('Search Results');
                    mainPanel.setActiveItem(lastPanelId);
                }
            }]
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem...have you transferred the updated app.css file to eclipse? If not, that's very likely the issue.

If not, is the Sencha code running (determined by plugging some alerts throughout the code)?